# MySQL UPDATE with subquery with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update, left-join

I have the following tables on MySQL:

```
**Elements**
+------+------------------+------------------+
+ Id   + Name             + referenced       +
+------+------------------+------------------+
+ 1    + element1         + NULL             +
+ 2    + element2         + NULL             +
+ 3    + element3         + NULL             +
+ 4    + element4         + NULL             +
+ 5    + element5         + NULL             +
+ 6    + element6         + NULL             +
+------+------------------+------------------+

**References**
+------+------------------+------------------+
+ Id   + Name             + type             +
+------+------------------+------------------+
+ 1    + element1         + 1                +
+ 2    + element1         + 2                +
+ 3    + element3         + 1                +
+ 4    + element3         + 2                +
+ 5    + element3         + 3                +
+ 6    + element4         + 1                +
+ 7    + element5         + 2                +
+ 8    + element5         + 3                +
+------+------------------+------------------+
```

The "referenced" column on "Elements" table should have 0 for no reference of its name on "References" table and 1 for at least one reference of its name on "References" table.

This result could be selected with the following query:

```
SELECT Elements.Id, Elements.Name, (References.Id is not null) as referenced FROM
    Elements 
LEFT JOIN 
    References ON Elements.Name = References.Name 
GROUP BY Elements.Name ORDER by Elements.Id;

+------+------------------+------------------+
+ Id   + Name             + referenced       +
+------+------------------+------------------+
+ 1    + element1         + 1                +
+ 2    + element2         + 0                +
+ 3    + element3         + 1                +
+ 4    + element4         + 1                +
+ 5    + element5         + 1                +
+ 6    + element6         + 0                +
+------+------------------+------------------+
```

But I could't find a way to update the "Elements" table with this result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Elements e
LEFT JOIN References r ON e.OneName = r.OtherName
SET e.referenced = r.OtherName IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Brilliant! And it worked very quick on a 200k row table! I had to temporarly rename the "Name" column on one of my tables because the column names were different. Any idea to solve this problem when the "Name" column have different names?

Comment: Edited the join above for when the column names are different.